# how to set the QML application window transparent by Qt 5.6?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am new in Qt & QML, now I set a window and want to set it transparent, user can see my desktop cross my application.
I try to use `WA_TranslucentBackground` and `opacity`, however it doesn't work.

Here is my QML code, it's very simple:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: Screen.width
    height: Screen.height
    title: qsTr("Input")
    flags: Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground | Qt.FramelessWindowHint

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }

    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Window {
    visible: true
    color: "transparent"
    //flags: Qt.Widget | Qt.FramelessWindowHint
}
```

Uncomment `flags` if you want transparent window without frame

Comment: If I want to set the background color to rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), and the user also can see anythind behind  my application, how can I do it ?

Comment: Just set `color: Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)`.

Comment: You can also try opacity: 0.5 for example

Comment: yes, it works, thanks. however I set the flag like  this,flags:  Qt.Dialog | Qt.FramelessWindowHint. it will be a black window. (I want to get a frameless and dialog window)

Comment: For what you need that? What is your real target?

Comment: I have 2 monitor screens , and I want to get a window: opacity is 0.3, and fullscreen on one of my monitor screens

Comment: Ok, but why exactly dialog window?